# Chainlink VRF avalanche

Tags: chainlink

How to get random number using chainlink in avalanche.

The V1 has support for Polygon, BSC and ETH.

https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-vrf/?_ga=2.132083400.616421178.1645534260-1388116974.1645534260

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time, Chainlink VRF is not available on Avalanche.